# What's the name of the sequence of differences?

Tags: terminology

Let $a = (a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ be an infinite sequence of real numbers.

What is the name of the sequence

\begin{equation*}
Da = (a_1 - a_0, a_2 - a_1, a_3 - a_2, \ldots) \qquad ?
\end{equation*}

Also, is the operator $D$ called the "forward difference operator"?

Comment: Do you need a fancier or shorter name than "sequence of consecutive differences"?  Defining "forward difference operator" $D$ by $(Da)_i = a_{i+1} - a_i$ seems like a very clear approach.

Comment: Alternatively, you word it as $D=S_l-I$ where $S_l$ is the canonical left-shift operator.  I.e. $S_l: (a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)\mapsto (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $Da$ is often called *the first difference of sequence $a$*. Search for *"first difference of" sequence* will bring up many examples of usage.

Naturally, $D^2a=D(D(a))$ is the second difference of $a$, and so on. Same terminology as with derivatives, except the word "derivative" is replaced with "sequence".

"Forward difference operator" is a standard term for $D$.